# is there a way to sort of sync the contents within 2 or more folders to another folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sync

So, while I have found methods that could be used to sync one folder to another singular folder, I have no found a method that could be used to reliably sync the contents of multiple folders to a singular other folder. By this I will give a real world usage example.

I play The Sims 4, I would like to have my Mods and Tray files properly organized. However, there are two issues with this, one being there can not be subfolders within the Tray folder, and the second being that .ts4script files can not be more than one folder deep within the Mods folder.

My thought for a possible solution was to have a folder on my external hard disk where I would have something similar to the following: [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNhmF.png)

I would then use a command shell script to sync the subfolders within the overarching TS4/Mods folder to the content of MyDocs/The Sims 4 folder like so: [poorly illustrated example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqLyC.png).

Essentially, the contents of the folders called "Folders" "Of" etc, would show up as the main contents of the folders "Mods" and "Tray".

The main dilemma here then is, I have no idea how to do any of that. I thought maybe I could use Robocopy, as it has a monitoring function, but I realized that it may not work as idealized when dealing with multiple locations to pull from and push to.

Another problem is the fact that, at least for the Tray folder, the fact that the game downloads directly to that folder whenever you grab an item from the Gallery poses it's own issues, that of... where should newly downloaded files go. It may be able to tell the difference between a .room and a .blueprint, but I doubt it could tell which one any particular .sgi file goes to which .room or .blueprint, thus it would probably be best to try and have any new downloads synced to a folder all their own, and I would then move them to their respective folders manually.

Any advice on solutions would be greatly welcomed, I have no idea what I'm doing, but my OCD is going up the wall every time I have to look at my Sims 4 folders.

I did find a user with a similar question, though a different use case here: [Is it possible to save a configuration of folder structures that can be used to restore files into their folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/1407257/is-it-possible-to-save-a-configuration-of-folder-structures-that-can-be-used-to)

However, their case differs from mine in that they didn't actually need to do it this way, and thus changed their question to obsolete without a proper answer being given. I, however, do need to do it this way as there is no ability for the game (TS4) to read from subfolders, and I can't stand disorganization. So, if I could simply have a properly organized set of folders on one drive, that would sync like above. I'd never have to actually look in the un-synced folders. Not to mention updating the files later on would be much easier, because I'd know exactly where everything is, and what it's for.

Comment: Do you know about symlinks? https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: Yes, but in this case a hard link would have to be used, and either way it's not exactly easy to manage as many files as I have manually.